# How to navigate to the XML file in which Imageview is declared, through Layout Inspector?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout, layout-inspector

I want to change some properties for imageview , problem is that imageview ID name is used for many imageview in project , I want to change only for the one which i am looking through layout inspector .

I saw in [this](https://youtu.be/jyMo18IERLc?t=172) video that we can navigate to the file through declared attributes , but the problem is i am not able to find Declared Attributes section in Layout Inspector .

[image]

P.S My Device is API 29 Level .

Answer (score 0):

find the activity name.xml than click spilt (see attached image) than find the image-view. now code & relative view is in-front of you and you can add whatever you want.

Secondly, you made a very big mistake it'll disturb you in up-coming requirements.

- Remember Never use same id for more than one view item

[image]